# Print 10 most frequently occurring words of a text that including and excluding stopwords

Tags: python, nltk, word-frequency, find-occurrences

I got the question from [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) with my changes. I have following code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
def content_text(text):
    stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
    content = [w for w in text if w.lower() in stopwords]
    return content
```

How can I **print** the 10 most frequently occurring words of a text that 1)**including** and 2)**excluding** stopwords?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a FreqDist function in nltk

```
import nltk
allWords = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
allWordDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords)

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
allWordExceptStopDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords if w not in stopwords)
```

to extract 10 most common:

```
mostCommon= allWordDist.most_common(10).keys()
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'most_common'

Comment: Can you please provide full listing?

Comment: You should ask stopwords with strings in lowercase.
From:

`allWordExceptStopDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords if w not in stopwords) `

To:

`allWordExceptStopDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords if w.lower() not in stopwords)`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure on the `is stopwords` in the function, I imagine it  needs to be `in`  but you can use a Counterdict with `most_common(10)` to get the 10 most frequent:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation


def content_text(text):
    stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')) # 0(1) lookups
    with_stp = Counter()
    without_stp  = Counter()
    with open(text) as f:
        for line in f:
            spl = line.split()
            # update count off all words in the line that are in stopwrods
            with_stp.update(w.lower().rstrip(punctuation) for w in spl if w.lower() in stopwords)
               # update count off all words in the line that are not in stopwords
            without_stp.update(w.lower().rstrip(punctuation)  for w in spl if w  not in stopwords)
    # return a list with top ten most common words from each 
    return [x for x in with_stp.most_common(10)],[y for y in without_stp.most_common(10)]
wth_stop, wthout_stop = content_text(...)
```

If you are passing in an nltk  file object just iterate over it:

```
def content_text(text):
    stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    with_stp = Counter()
    without_stp  = Counter()
    for word in text:
        # update count off all words in the line that are in stopwords
        word = word.lower()
        if word in stopwords:
             with_stp.update([word])
        else:
           # update count off all words in the line that are not in stopwords
            without_stp.update([word])
    # return a list with top ten most common words from each
    return [k for k,_ in with_stp.most_common(10)],[y for y,_ in without_stp.most_common(10)]

print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('2009-Obama.txt')))
```

The nltk method includes punctuation so that may not be what you want.

Comment: when I write `wth_stop, wthout_stop = content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('2009-Obama.txt'))` I get error.

Comment: @user2064809, I tested it and it works fine for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, StreamBackedCorpusView found

Comment: what should I put exactly inside `content_text()` function?

Comment: just put `'2009-Obama.txt'`

Comment: @user2064809: You might have to make some changes to the code if you are using python 2. Also, if need help understanding an error message, you need to provide all of it. It's much easier to understand when we know exactly where in the script the exception was raised.

Comment: I was just guessing based on the error message. A lot of functions that used to return ascii strings or simple structures such as lists in python 2, will return unicode and more complicated, but efficient iterators such as Views in python 3. Could it perhaps be caused by a different version of nltk?

Comment: @HåkenLid,  the error was because the OP was passing an nltk object to the first function instead of just a file name

Comment: That's all good then. Are you sure the last line in your snippet will run properly, though? There's two closing parentheses missing, and you'll probably have to import `print_function` with python 2.

Comment: @HåkenLid, that was just a typo from copy/pasting. There is no need to import `print_function`.

Comment: It works! thank you. I should put 'computer address' in first code: `wth_stop, wthout_stop = content_text('C:\\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\\nltk_data\\corpora\\inaugural\\2009-Obama.txt')` instead of `nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('2009-Obama.txt')`. But in the second code the `print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('2009-Obama.txt')))` works!!

Comment: @user2064809, I was not sure what exactly you were passing as text so I just added a way to use a normal file and an nltk file object. The first example will work for any  file. just pass the path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for word, frequency in allWordsDist.most_common(10):
    print('%s;%d' % (word, frequency)).encode('utf-8')
```